# How does Java handle fields when upcasting?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The concept of shadowing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300805/the-concept-of-shadowing)

I am confused about how the fields of classes are handled in Java during upcasting. For example:

```
class SuperClass
{
    String myString = "String in SuperClass";

    public void myMethod()
    {
        System.out.println("Method in SuperClass");
    }
}

class SubClass extends SuperClass
{
    String myString = "String in SubClass";

    public void myMethod()
    {
        System.out.println("Method in SubClass");
    }
}

class Question
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SuperClass test = new SubClass();
            // object test is an instance of SubClass
            // but I am telling the compiler to treat it as SuperClass

        test.myMethod();
        System.out.println(test.myString);

    }
}
```

Output:

```
Method in SubClass
String in SuperClass //Why is "String in SubClass" not used?
```

When I create an object `test` it is an instance of `SubClass` class; however, I am telling the compiler to treat it as `SuperClass`. Everything is clear to me about methods work: I will only be able to use the methods of the `SubClass`, if a given method is defined for `SuperClass`.

However, I am lost as to why a field of a `SuperClass` is used when I try to access `myString` of `test`. Since `test` is an instance of `SubClass` I would expect `myString` defined in `SubClass` to be used, why is this not happening? What am I missing?

I know that I can access, myString of `SubClass` by using `this` operator. For example, I could define `printMyString` method in SuperClass, and overwrite it with

```
public void printMyString()
{
    System.out.println(this.myString);
}
```

In the `SubClass`, so my question is mostly about how come the field of the `SuperClass` is used in `test`. Maybe I am missing something obvious?

I tried to search for the answer, and the closest topic I found was [Upcasting in Java and two separate object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10653845/upcasting-in-java-and-two-separate-object-properties/10653912#10653912), though helpful, it did not answer my question.

Thank You in Advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Attributes cant be overloaded like methods.

```
test.myMethod();
```

Here method invocation depends on the *type of actual object*. Here object is of type `SubClass` so method of `SubClass` is invoked.

```
test.myString
```

While accessing attributes,it depends on the *type of reference variable*. Here reference variable ie `test` is of type `SuperClass` so attribute from `SuperClass` is accessed.

What you are looking is [class variable hiding / shadowing](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/what-is-variable-hiding-and-shadowing/15).

Comment: Nice link, thank you. The key part is: "When an instance variable in a subclass has the same name as an instance variable in a super class, then the instance variable is chosen in the class that is the reference type."

Comment: @Akavall: Ya you hit the point :)

Answer (score 5):

Fields in Java are **only hidden and not actually overridden** (that doesn't mean that we'll get a compile time error while trying this, instead they are not overridden in its true sense).

> Overriding means the member should be invoked based on the *run time
> type of the object* and not based on the declared type.

But binding for fields in Java is always static and hence it's based on the *declared type of the object reference* only.

In the example you've given, by declaring the class variable with the name 'myString' in class `SubClass` you hide the class variable it would have inherited from its superclass `SuperClass` with the same name 'myString'.

Java language specification :

> If the class declares a field with a certain name, then the
> declaration of that field is said to hide any and all accessible
> declarations of fields with the same name in superclasses, and
> superinterfaces of the class.
>
> A hidden field can be accessed by using a qualified name if it is static, or by using a field access expression that contains the keyword super or a cast to a superclass type.